# Linux acting as a router - port-forwarding

Tags: linux, networking, routing, forwarding

Trying to setup a little AWS Box (Debian Linux) to act as a router taking public traffic (eth0 - single network interface) and redirecting it to a different public IP address, different ports and then send the traffic back to the clients.

*The port mappings (TCP & UDP):*
Src-IP, Src-Port, Dest-IP, Dest-Port

ALL, 27106,168.119.149.150,27015

ALL, 8000,168.119.149.150,7777

ALL, 8001,168.119.149.150,7778

***What I am trying to get to happen:***

**Traffic in:**
Public IP (Client App) [27106,8000,8001] -> Linux Box -> Destination Public Server (AA) [27015,7777,7778]

**Return Traffic:**
Public Server (AA) [27015,7777,7778] -> Linux Box -> Public IP (Client App) [27106,8000,8001]

The /etc/iptables/rules.v4 is currently:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 27106 -j DNAT --to-destination 168.119.149.150:27015
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 27106 -j DNAT --to-destination 168.119.149.150:27015
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination 168.119.149.150:7777
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination 168.119.149.150:7777
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8001 -j DNAT --to-destination 168.119.149.150:7778
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 8001 -j DNAT --to-destination 168.119.149.150:7778
-A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 27015
-A POSTROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 27015
-A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7777
-A POSTROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 7777
-A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7778
-A POSTROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 7778
COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
```

The `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/forwarding` returns 1

The AWS Firewall end-points are configured to accept all traffic [TCP/UDP] - so its not that, I can only think I've not setup the rules file incorrectly?

### *The problem, is it doesn't seem to be working as I'm expecting it to - can anyone give some pointers on what I'm doing wrong?*

Comment: Host your gameserver somewhere that already has WAF/DDOS protection, like that AWS instance.

Comment: Not a viable solution for this one, as I want to move the Linux box somewhere else and hide the IP Address of where the real game server is and have the linux box as the 'front-door' for all traffic.

Comment: This question is Off topic on server fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security AWS doesn't allow it.

> Amazon EC2 instances cannot send spoofed network traffic. The
> AWS-controlled, host-based firewall infrastructure will not permit an
> instance to send traffic with a source IP or MAC address other than
> its own.

[PDF Source](https://personal.utdallas.edu/%7Emuratk/courses/cloud11f_files/AWS_Security_Whitepaper.pdf)

You can try nat the  outbound traffic.

Comment: Perfect - I added -j MASQUERADE   to the pathing and that did the trick.